latex resume editable
I just want to make my Skills Summary in two multicols as in this picture

%------------------------
% Resume Template
% Author : Ahmed Abdelazeem
% Github : https://github.com/abdelazeem201
% License : MIT
%------------------------

\documentclass[a4paper,20pt]{article}

\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage[empty]{fullpage}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{marvosym}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{color}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage[pdftex]{hyperref}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{} % clear all header and footer fields
\fancyfoot{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}

% Adjust margins
\addtolength{\oddsidemargin}{-0.530in}
\addtolength{\evensidemargin}{-0.375in}
\addtolength{\textwidth}{1in}
\addtolength{\topmargin}{-.45in}
\addtolength{\textheight}{1in}

\urlstyle{rm}

\raggedbottom
\raggedright
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0in}

% Sections formatting
\titleformat{\section}{
    \vspace{-10pt}\scshape\raggedright\large
}{}{0em}{}[\color{black}\titlerule \vspace{-6pt}]

%-------------------------
% Custom commands
\newcommand{\resumeItem}[2]{
    \item\small{
        \textbf{#1}{: #2 \vspace{-2pt}}
    }
}

\newcommand{\resumeItemWithoutTitle}[1]{
    \item\small{
        {\vspace{-2pt}}
    }
}

\newcommand{\resumeSubheading}[4]{
    \vspace{-1pt}\item
    \begin{tabular*}{0.97\textwidth}{l@{\extracolsep{\fill}}r}
        \textbf{#1} & #2 \\
        \textit{#3} & \textit{#4} \\
    \end{tabular*}\vspace{-5pt}
}


\newcommand{\resumeSubItem}[2]{\resumeItem{#1}{#2}\vspace{-3pt}}

\renewcommand{\labelitemii}{$\circ$}

\newcommand{\resumeSubHeadingListStart}{\begin{itemize}[leftmargin=*]}
    \newcommand{\resumeSubHeadingListEnd}{\end{itemize}}
\newcommand{\resumeItemListStart}{\begin{itemize}}
    \newcommand{\resumeItemListEnd}{\end{itemize}\vspace{-5pt}}

%-----------------------------
%%%%%%  CV STARTS HERE  %%%%%%

\begin{document}
    
    %----------HEADING-----------------
    \begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{l@{\extracolsep{\fill}}r}
        \textbf{{\LARGE }} & Email: \href{mailto:}{}\\
        \href{}{LinkedIn: } & Mobile:~~~+0000000000 \\
        \href{https://github.com/abdelazeem201}{Github: ~~abdelazeem201} \\
    \end{tabular*}
    
    
    \vspace{-5pt}
    \section{Skills Summary}
    \resumeSubHeadingListStart
    \resumeSubItem{Languages}{~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~C, Python, MATLAB, TCL}
    \resumeSubItem{HDL(RTL)}{~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~Verilog, VHDL}
    \resumeSubItem{Logic Synthesis}{~~~~~~~~~DC(Synopsys), Genus(Cadence)}
    \resumeSubItem{Place \& Route}{~~~~~~~~~~ICC (II) (Synopsys), Innovus (Cadence)}
    \resumeSubItem{Signoff tools}{~~~~~~~~~~~~ StarRC, PrimeTime, Calibre, Virtuoso}
    \resumeSubItem{Other Tools}{~~~~~~~~~~~~~~HSpice, Vivado, VCS, QuestaSim.}
    \resumeSubItem{Physical Verification}{~LVS, DRC, Density rules}
    \resumeSubItem{Technologies}{~~~~~~~~~~~~~Linux, GitHub, Git, \LaTeX}
    \resumeSubHeadingListEnd
        
\end{document}



You could use the multicol package:
%------------------------
% Resume Template
% Author : Ahmed Abdelazeem
% Github : https://github.com/abdelazeem201
% License : MIT
%------------------------

\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage[empty]{fullpage}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{marvosym}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{color}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage[pdftex]{hyperref}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{multicol}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{} % clear all header and footer fields
\fancyfoot{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
\setlength{\footskip}{3.6004pt}

% Adjust margins
\addtolength{\oddsidemargin}{-0.530in}
\addtolength{\evensidemargin}{-0.375in}
\addtolength{\textwidth}{1in}
\addtolength{\topmargin}{-.45in}
\addtolength{\textheight}{1in}

\urlstyle{rm}

\raggedbottom
\raggedright
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0in}

% Sections formatting
\titleformat{\section}{
    \vspace{-10pt}\scshape\raggedright\large
}{}{0em}{}[\color{black}\titlerule \vspace{-6pt}]

%-------------------------
% Custom commands
\newcommand{\resumeItem}[2]{
    \item\small{
        \textbf{#1}{: #2 \vspace{-2pt}}
    }
}

\newcommand{\resumeItemWithoutTitle}[1]{
    \item\small{
        {\vspace{-2pt}}
    }
}

\newcommand{\resumeSubheading}[4]{
    \vspace{-1pt}\item
    \begin{tabular*}{0.97\textwidth}{l@{\extracolsep{\fill}}r}
        \textbf{#1} & #2 \\
        \textit{#3} & \textit{#4} \\
    \end{tabular*}\vspace{-5pt}
}


\newcommand{\resumeSubItem}[2]{\resumeItem{#1}{#2}\vspace{-3pt}}

\renewcommand{\labelitemii}{$\circ$}

\newcommand{\resumeSubHeadingListStart}{\begin{itemize}[leftmargin=*]}
    \newcommand{\resumeSubHeadingListEnd}{\end{itemize}}
\newcommand{\resumeItemListStart}{\begin{itemize}}
    \newcommand{\resumeItemListEnd}{\end{itemize}\vspace{-5pt}}

%-----------------------------
%%%%%%  CV STARTS HERE  %%%%%%

\begin{document}
    
    %----------HEADING-----------------
    \begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{l@{\extracolsep{\fill}}r}
        \textbf{{\LARGE }} & Email: \href{mailto:}{}\\
        \href{}{LinkedIn: } & Mobile:~~~+0000000000 \\
        \href{https://github.com/abdelazeem201}{Github: ~~abdelazeem201} \\
    \end{tabular*}
    
    \section{Skills Summary}
    \begin{multicols}{2}
    \resumeSubHeadingListStart
    \resumeSubItem{Languages}{C, Python, MATLAB, TCL}
    \resumeSubItem{HDL(RTL)}{Verilog, VHDL}
    \resumeSubItem{Logic Synthesis}{DC(Synopsys), Genus(Cadence)}
    \resumeSubItem{Place \& Route}{ICC (II) (Synopsys), Innovus (Cadence)}
    \resumeSubItem{Signoff tools}{StarRC, PrimeTime, Calibre, Virtuoso}
    \resumeSubItem{Other Tools}{HSpice, Vivado, VCS, QuestaSim.}
    \resumeSubItem{Physical Verification}{LVS, DRC, Density rules}
    \resumeSubItem{Technologies}{Linux, GitHub, Git, \LaTeX}
    \resumeSubHeadingListEnd
        \end{multicols}
        
\end{document}


